# Can I bypass a trace from the diode to the solder point with wire?

Tags: pcb, trace, damage, bypass

I'm working on the button/power motherboard of an X-Box one's controller - the menu (start) button doesn't work.

I think there might be damage to the trace when I followed the trace to the solder point.

If it is just the trace, can I bypass it from the diode to the solder point with wire, or what would be the best simple fix?

The trace I suspect is broken follows SW5 down and I suspect it is broken after the diode:

[image]

Comment: Take the picture and use an image editor (e.g. [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.net/)) to _resample_ the image to a smaller size.

Comment: I'm only on a phone and I can't find software that will downgrade my photo to less than 2 MiB and any screen shots load as text, sorry

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and fixed the image embedding. Still it doesn't say much about what you are trying to fix. In general if a track is broken, yes, you can bypass it with wire.

Comment: Sorry yeah I'm not very good at this, it's my first forum haha thank you for doing that, I do have a picture of the actual circuit board but I can't upload it, I'll try bypassing it and if it works ill let you know if not ill try explaining/presenting a bit better

Comment: @Drew3121:  [Snapseed is free, and can crop and scale images.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed)  You insert images in the  question editor by clicking the "image" button (mountains with a sun icon.)